# RestKit 0.20 POST JSON with nested array

Tags: restkit

I have an object called Client which looks something like this.

```
@interface Client : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * middleName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Styles *clientStyles;
@end
```

Styles is a nested object underneath Client.  It's a One to One relationship.  When this comes down from the server in JSON it looks like this.

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "firstStyle": {
        "styleId": 4,
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "stylingTime": "55 min",
        "stylingProductUsage": "A lot",
        "chemicals": "LOTS O'GEL",
        "deleted": false,
        "modifiedOn": 1357161168830
    }
}
```

Everything is in a nice single object.  I can pull this down and map it to my object no problem.  The issue comes in when I need to return this back to the server.  It needs to be in this format.

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "styles": [
        {
            "styleId": 4,
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "stylingTime": "55 min",
            "stylingProductUsage": "A lot",
            "chemicals": "LOTS O'GEL",
            "deleted": false,
            "modifiedOn": 1357161168830
        }]
```

}

Which is very problematic because the return mapping has the styles entity sitting inside an array, rather then being a one-to-one.  So far I have got this as my RKRequestDescriptor

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"firstName": @"firstName",
     @"middleName": @"middleName",
     @"lastName": @"lastName",
 }];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor  requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[Client class]
                                                                               rootKeyPath:nil];
```

How the HECK do I create the mapping so it will return an array of Style objects with one value???

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but the mappings are pretty smart, can't you do something like:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"firstName": @"firstName",
     @"middleName": @"middleName",
     @"lastName": @"lastName",
 }];

RKObjectMapping *stylesMappingDescription = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"properties": @"here"
 }];

[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"styles.0" toKeyPath:@"styles" withMapping:stylesMappingDescription]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor      requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[Client class]
                                                                           rootKeyPath:nil];
```

(note the styles.0 as `fromKeyPath`)